# Beginner Flask Site Issue

Tags: python, flask, backend

I'm trying to run my first flask site, but it just brings up the "This site can't be reached" message. What am I doing wrong?
Code:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def welcome():
    return f"<h1>Welcome!</h1>"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `host='0.0.0.0'` with your IP Address or you can just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Just return localhost for your development needs, even it comes to production it's okay because you could connect the app with Nginx/Apache.